# Собственная глобальная переменная потока

Tags: c, unix, многопоточность

Есть рабочая библиотека, которую необходимо использовать в многопоточном приложении. Все ошибки из вызовов данной библиотеки возвращаются через глобальную переменную, описанную в этой же библиотеке. Проанализировав код функций, становится понятно, что некоторую часть из них можно было бы беспрепятственно использовать в многопоточном приложении, если бы не эта глобальная переменная с кодом ошибки. Пока что мне приходилось в подобных случаях переписывать функции библиотеки, передавая в них указатель на переменную, куда сохранять код ошибки, это решение мне не нравится, так как ведет к полному перелопачиванию библиотеки.

Насколько мне известно, когда-то переменная *errno* тоже была глобальной для всей программы, но спустя некоторое время она была переопределена глобальной в пределах потока, т.е. для каждого потока выполнения она своя. Может ли кто-то подсказать, как проделать то же самое, или что-то близкое по смыслу с переменной кода ошибки в библиотеке, чтобы она была для каждого потока - своя, и чтобы не приходилось переписывать всю библиотеку?

Comment: Посмотрите https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html (TLS, оно же `thread variable` для поиска в гугле)

Comment: @Abyx,@avp, спасибо, буду смотреть

Comment: margosh, еще для таких целей используют [pthread_setspecific/pthread_getspecific](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_getspecific) / (сам ни разу не пробовал)

Comment: @avp, читала про локальные данные потоков, тоже  на практике не использовала пока, не уверена, что они к данной ситуации применимы

Comment: тоесть, не уверена, что использование _setspecific/_getspecific подойдет, а вот спецификатор __thread похож на то, что нужно. Жаль конечно, что архитектурно-зависим...

Comment: margosh, ну, навскидку. Обращения к переменной вне библиотеки  можно сделать макросом, одноименным к этой переменной, который вызывает функцию, которая использует pthread_self как ключ для pthread_getspecific / Ну, а внутри библиотеки можно сделать что-то похожее с макросом и  функцией, возвращающей указатель на переменную (тоже упрятанную в set/getspecific) / Как-то так, наверное аналогично может быть реализована и errno

Comment: Т.е. в библиотеке идея реализации такая -- `#define err_no (*xerr())

static int *xerr() { static int x[2] = {5,6}; return x + time(0) % 2; }
`

Comment: @avp, если найдете время, оформите в ответ с примером по возможности пожалуйста, а я поэкспериментирую с этими вызовами.

Comment: @Abyx: Почему же OS, с C++11 это в стандарте: [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: @Abyx: А, это C, а не C++. Ну википедия говорит, что [есть и в C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#C_and_C.2B.2B).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@margosh, немного почитал маны и вот что получилось (интересующую Вас переменную обозвал `lib_errno`, при создании (первое обращение к ней) в каждом потоке она обнуляется):

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ more ptlib.h ptlib.c c.c | cat
::::::::::::::
ptlib.h
::::::::::::::
#ifndef _PTLIB_H
#define _PTLIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  pid_t gettid(void);
  int *lib_errno_func(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#define lib_errno (*lib_errno_func())

#endif
::::::::::::::
ptlib.c
::::::::::::::
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#include "ptlib.h"

pid_t
gettid()
{
  return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}

static pthread_once_t key_is_initialized = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
static pthread_key_t key;

static void
destruct_thread_value (void *ptr)
{
  printf("destruct: %ld %p value %d\n",
         (long)gettid(), ptr, ptr ? *((int *)ptr) : 0);
  free(ptr);
}

static void
make_key ()
{
  printf("make_key: %ld\n", (long)gettid());
  pthread_key_create(&key, destruct_thread_value);
}

int *
lib_errno_func ()
{
  int *ptr;

  pthread_once(&key_is_initialized, make_key);
  if (!(ptr = (typeof(ptr))pthread_getspecific(key))) {
    ptr = (typeof(ptr))calloc(sizeof(int), 1);
    printf("construct: %ld %p\n", (long)gettid(), ptr);
    pthread_setspecific(key, ptr);
  }

  return ptr;
}

::::::::::::::
c.c
::::::::::::::
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "ptlib.h"


void *
tfunc (void *a)
{
  usleep(rand() % 100000);
  printf("thread-run: tid=%ld a=%d lib_errno=%d\n", 
         (long)gettid(), *((int *)a), lib_errno);
  lib_errno = *((int *)a) + 100;
  usleep(rand() % 100000);
  printf("thread-fin: tid=%ld a=%d lib_errno=%d\n", 
         (long)gettid(), *((int *)a), lib_errno);

  return 0;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "3");
  if (n < 1)
    n = 3;
  pthread_t tid[n];

  printf("main-run: tid=%ld lib_errno=%d\n", (long)gettid(), lib_errno);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int *pv = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pv = i;
    pthread_create(tid + i, 0, tfunc, pv);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    pthread_join(tid[i], 0);

  printf("main-fin: tid=%ld lib_errno=%d\n", (long)gettid(), lib_errno);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc -pthread  -O2 -c ptlib.c -Wall
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ -pthread c.c ptlib.o
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
make_key: 5556
construct: 5556 0x8ca010
main-run: tid=5556 lib_errno=0
construct: 5558 0x7f22c40008c0
thread-run: tid=5558 a=1 lib_errno=0
thread-fin: tid=5558 a=1 lib_errno=101
destruct: 5558 0x7f22c40008c0 value 101
construct: 5557 0x7f22c40008c0
thread-run: tid=5557 a=0 lib_errno=0
construct: 5559 0x7f22bc0008c0
thread-run: tid=5559 a=2 lib_errno=0
thread-fin: tid=5559 a=2 lib_errno=102
destruct: 5559 0x7f22bc0008c0 value 102
thread-fin: tid=5557 a=0 lib_errno=100
destruct: 5557 0x7f22c40008c0 value 100
main-fin: tid=5556 lib_errno=0
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

На первый взгляд, вроде работает...

Comment: Отлично! Работают оба варианта.   @avp, спасибо за пример, очень наглядно

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, уже давно практически все компиляторы предоставляют собственные средства для создания thread local переменных. В MSVC это `declspec(thread)`, в GCC - `__thread`.

Во-вторых, начиная с С11 в языке появился стандартный спецификатор `_Thread_local`, объявляющий thread local переменные.

В любом случае, можно просто подсмотреть, что сделано на вашей платформе с `errno` и повторить то же самое.